# Nested Objects in JS

Tags: javascript, object, nested

I have the following nested Objects:

```
var john = {
  name: 'John',
  greet: {
    first: function () { console.log('greet > first') },
    inside: function () { this.first() }
  }
};
john.greet.inside();
```

This will output: 'greet > first', but how do I call 'name' (john.name) from the inside function?

Jo

Comment: You are prob better off making two methods `greetFirst` etc as part of john object. If you opt to go with a separate greeter obj, it should probably have a person property, which stores reference to john.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, if I use binding like this:

```
john.greet.inside.bind(john)();
```

Then this will be referring to the Object john and I can use:

```
this.name
```